# Why cypress config is invalid when I try to run npx cypress open?

Tags: cypress

I've already installed cypress and I once successfully open it and run some example test cases. I don't know why when I try to open it again with command `npx cypress open` in vscode it says

Cypress Configuration Error

[image: 1]

This is the stack trace:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'cypress'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\janna\Documents\Miftah's folder\Learn\Cypress\gitRepo\ngx-cypress-test\cypress.config.js
- C:\Users\janna\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.6.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_require_async_child.js
- C:\Users\janna\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.6.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\require_async_child.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (C:\Users\janna\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.6.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:679:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object. (C:\Users\janna\Documents\Miftah's folder\Learn\Cypress\gitRepo\ngx-cypress-test\cypress.config.js:1:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at loadFile (C:\Users\janna\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.6.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_require_async_child.js:89:14)
    at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\janna\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\10.6.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\@packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_require_async_child.js:116:38)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at EventEmitter.emit (node:domain:475:12)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can fix that file with `watchForFileChanges: false,`

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    watchForFileChanges: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```